# Consistent Gradle error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-appcompat

Hi I am not sure what is wrong with my android studio but I have tried everything and am not sure what this error means..

I have just uninstalled and re-installed android studio..

Here is a screenshot of the gradle error:

[image: GradleError]

Has anyone seen this error before?

app.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.almac.tracker"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
       testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.github.bmarrdev:android-DecoView-charting:v1.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.6.2'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.2'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9'
compile 'com.akexorcist:RoundCornerProgressBar:2.0.3' 
compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.2.1'
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

styles:

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_default
    </item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have the `AppCompat` dependency in your `app.gradle` file

```
dependencies{
   ...
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Yeah I do @Hassan.. I have 26.1.0 corresponding to the target sdk of 26.. still same problem wont work for any application

Comment: could you include your `app.gradle` and your `style` file

Comment: I have updated my original post with what you have asked for

Comment: are you referencing `@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` in one of your layout views in any `.xml` file

Comment: Nope I am just using that theme